# What is actually happening when executing a tensorflow graph using python API?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a newbie to tensorflow. But I think understanding about tesnorflow core operation is a must. If we use tf python API with object oriented manner we can fist create different graph operations as definition.

```
def _create_placeholders(self):
    """ Step 1: define the placeholders for input and output """
    with tf.name_scope("data"):
        self.center_words = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size], name='center_words')
        print("Extracting the op",self.center_words.op)
        self.target_words = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size, 1], name='target_words')
        print("so",self.center_words.op)

def _create_embedding(self):
    """ Step 2: define weights. In word2vec, it's actually the weights that we care about """
    # Assemble this part of the graph on the CPU. You can change it to GPU if you have GPU
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        with tf.name_scope("embed"):
            self.embed_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([self.vocab_size, 
                                                                self.embed_size], -1.0, 1.0), 
                                                                name='embed_matrix')

def _create_loss(self):
    """ Step 3 + 4: define the model + the loss function """
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        with tf.name_scope("loss"):
            # Step 3: define the inference
            embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embed_matrix, self.center_words, name='embed')

            # Step 4: define loss function
            # construct variables for NCE loss
            nce_weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.vocab_size, self.embed_size],
                                                        stddev=1.0 / (self.embed_size ** 0.5)), 
                                                        name='nce_weight')
            nce_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([VOCAB_SIZE]), name='nce_bias')


            # define loss function to be NCE loss function
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weight, 
                                                biases=nce_bias, 
                                                labels=self.target_words, 
                                                inputs=embed, 
                                                num_sampled=self.num_sampled, 
                                                num_classes=self.vocab_size), name='loss')
```

Here I have mentioned two definitions which are for creating embedding and calculate loss. 
So if I run one of this def with **_create_loss()** it will create a node in the graph. I went through the tf source code , What I saw was during the graph building stage is in that stage it will load each any every operation to  some-kind of buffer. 
Then during the session we just re run each and everything with real data.

```
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname('c/checkpointsq'))
    # if that checkpoint exists, restore from checkpoint
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        print("Restoring the checkpoins")
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

    total_loss = 0.0 # we use this to calculate late average loss in the last SKIP_STEP steps
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./ improved_graph/lr' + str(LEARNING_RATE), sess.graph)
    initial_step = model.global_step.eval()

    for index in range(1):
        centers, targets = batch_gen.__next__()
        feed_dict={model.center_words: centers, model.target_words: targets}
        loss_batch, _, summary = sess.run([model.loss, model.optimizer, model.summary_op], 
                                          feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Here is my problem. Here in sess.run tensorflow doesn't even care about the python API. It's only care about the graph operation which was loaded from the above graph initialization code. ***My question is where's all this operations are get executed in a session object. I can understand it's in the core. Do we have any access to that?***

Comment: what kind of access do you want ? do you want to debug the graph and see intermediate inputs/outputs for example?

Comment: I need to know where all the graphs are getting executed ?

Comment: They are executed by the C++ code of tensorflow or the CUDA portions if you use a GPU

Comment: I got this problem because I was searching where can I find the implementation for the auto differentiation since tensorflow only has forward implementation. I was searching for it's backward API. So all we should care about is building a graph and there's no simple python expression to just view the auto differentiation in tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code that builds the backpropagation part of the graph is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L327).

compute_gradients() is called by minimize(), which is then called by user code.

The scheduling and execution of ops in a already built TensorFlow graph happen inside this [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L374).

Comment: got it.  So as my last question   this **Status DirectSession::Run** merges all the graphs in to the C++ implementation and do the computations.

Comment: Yeah, a already built graph is passed to the session at DirectSession::Create, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L332, and DirectSession::Run will run all ops in this graph.